# Invoke angular function in console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, console

I am a novice.I have a line of code like this that was written for me.

```
<a class="pull-right btn btn-primary" ng-click="addWidget()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Widget</a>
```

Which works perfectly (it adds the widget which is a box element to the page). The function is defined in the controller DashboarCtrl like this

```
    $scope.addWidget = function() {
        $scope.dashboard.widgets.push({
            name: "New Widget",
            sizeX: 1,
            sizeY: 1
        });
    };
```

How do invoke that same function in the console? I have tried 
     angular.element('#DashboardCtrl').scope().addWidget();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets just say that your add Widget link has an id (add_widget). Then you can find the element by id and `click` it.

```
<a id="add_widget" class="pull-right btn btn-primary" ng-click="addWidget()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Widget
</a>
```

`angular.element('#add_widget').click();`

Comment: So simple when one knows. Thank you, that is it.